# RequestNavigation is not work in my wpf programs with prism libarary

Tags: dialog, prism

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ume8m.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88Im.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNRzM.png)I using IDialogService Open a View ,in a view I denifine a region ,when I try to use

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.VedioWallRegion, nameof(TwoWallView));
```

to navigate ,but it do not work . how can i resolve it,
how can i resole it  ,who can help me

Comment: do you mean that the region you want to navigate is inside a dialog?